# How To Deal With MaxLineLengthExceeded With Indy TIdTCPClient

Tags: indy

I'm new to indy, using whatever version comes with CBuilder XE4. Here's very simple code that works fine until what I'm reading exceeds the 16K limit....

```
String Ttcp_mgr::send(String data)
{
  tcpClient->Socket->WriteLn(data); 
  return tcpClient->Socket->ReadLn();
}
```

The server is not using indy, there is no length header, going both ways is json terminated by \r\n. Blocking reads are fine, there's nothing for my app to do until it get's it's response, and it will be coming very quickly anyway. But the amount of data that is returned could be a few bytes or 100K, in a few cases. Generally the length will be < 500 bytes.

I've looked at IOHandler but I have no idea how to apply it to what I'm doing, not even sure it's what I need. As you can probably tell I'm not using the component on a form which probably makes no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TIdIOHandler::ReadLn()` has an optional `AMaxLineLength` input parameter.  If you do not specify a value for it, the `TIdIOHandler::MaxLineLength` property is used, which is set to 16K by default.  The `TIdIOHandler::MaxLineAction` property specifies what happens if `ReadLn()` actually reaches the max line length.

If `MaxLineAction` is `maException` (the default), an `EIdReadLnMaxLineLengthExceeded` exception is raised.

If `MaxLineAction` is `maSplit`, the `TIdIOHandler::ReadLnSplit` property is set to true and `ReadLn()` returns what it can.  You would have to call `ReadLn()` again to read more data for the current line.  This can end up chopping the data incorrectly if it is using a multi-byte encoding for non-ASCII characters, like UTF-8 (which is JSON's default encoding), so I do not recommend this approach.

In your case, you should either:

1. set the `TIdIOHandler::MaxLineLength` property to `MaxInt`:

   ```
   // TIdTCPClient::OnConnected event handler...
   void __fastcall Ttcp_mgr::tcpCllientConnected(TObject *Sender)
   {
       tcpClient->IOHandler->MaxLineLength = MaxInt;
   }
   ```
2. pass `MaxInt` as a parameter to `TIdIOHandler::ReadLn()`.

   ```
   String Ttcp_mgr::send(String data)
   {
       tcpClient->Socket->WriteLn(data); 
       return tcpClient->Socket->ReadLn(EOL, IdTimeoutDefault, MaxInt);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

To all Delphi users: setting IOHandler.MaxLineLength to "MaxInt" must be done after starting the connection, otherwise you will get a memory error.

```
IdPOP31.Connect;
IdPOP31.IOHandler.MaxLineLength := MaxInt;
```

Everything else works as above, and solves the problem of parsing too long emails for Delphi.